# Swift convert Data to UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unsafe-pointers

I'm calling a function in an objective c class from swift.

```
-(char *)decrypt:(char *)crypt el:(int)el{}
```

when calling this function from swift,  it asks for an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>` as the value for the parameter *'crypt'*

the value for the *'crypt'* is comming from a server and it is a base64encoded string. So I decode that string and got a Data object.

```
let resultData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String)
```

Now I need to pass this data to the above mentioned function. I have tried to convert this Data object to a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`

```
resultData?.withUnsafeBytes { (u8Ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>) in
                    let decBytes = tea?.decrypt(u8Ptr , el: el)}
```

But it is not compiling. Gives below error

> 'UnsafeMutablePointer' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<_>'

I don't know much about objective c. So could anyone help me to pass this parameter to objective c function.

Comment: check this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747190/unsafepointeruint8-initializer-in-swift-3

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish I checked the answer. It says to use below code
var ptr = data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self). But the data.bytes is unavailable in swift 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to change `UnsafeMutablePointer` to  `UnsafePointer`

*UnsafePointer*

```
resultData?.withUnsafeBytes {(bytes: UnsafePointer<CChar>)->Void in
            //Use `bytes` inside this closure

        }
```

*UnsafeMutablePointer*

```
 var data2 = Data(capacity: 1024)
data2.withUnsafeMutableBytes({ (bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
                 //Use `bytes` inside this closure

            })
```

Comment: I used your second code and changed UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) to UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>). Now its working. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I get Error: 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' is not convertible to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>'

Answer (score 3):

Edit, updated my answer for two things:

- Not returning the pointer from withUnsafeBytes
- Accounting for Swift 5' deprecation warning: *'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead*

```
// buffer pointer captured is converted to byte pointer which is used in the block to decode the base64 encoded Data
encodedStringData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (rawBufferPtr: UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) in
    if let rawPtr = rawBufferPtr.baseAddress {
        let decodedString = String(bytesNoCopy: rawPtr, length: rawBufferPtr.count, encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: false)
        print(decodedString!)
    }
}
```

```
someData.withUnsafeBytes { (bufferRawPtr: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
        // For converting an UnsafeRawBufferPointer to its typed variant, in this case UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>
            let bufferTypedPtr = bufferRawPtr.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self)

        // Then, getting the typed UnsafePointer, in this case UnsafePointer<UInt8>
            let unsafePointer = bufferTypedPtr.baseAddress!
        }
```

Note: Swift 5 doesn't allow you to access `encodedStringData` from within the `withUnsafeMutableBytes` block! Read [Swift 5 Exclusivity Enforcement](https://swift.org/blog/swift-5-exclusivity/) for `why`.

*Capturing the pointer outside of the block is apparently not recommended, it works but the behavior can get to be undefined in the future*

Old answer:

This will help someone looking for getting to the underlying raw bytes (in a `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` representation) of a `Data` object as a **variable** for further use (instead of having to write all of the logic in the `withUnsafeMutableBytes` block).

```
var encodedStringData = Data(base64Encoded: "Vmlub2QgaXMgZ3JlYXQh")!
    
// byte pointer variable used later to decode the base64 encoded Data
let rawPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = encodedStringData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (bytePtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) in bytePtr }

let decodedString = String(bytesNoCopy: rawPtr, length: encodedStringData.count, encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: false)

print(decodedString, encodedStringData)
```

Comment: Don't let your unsafe pointers escape the `withUnsafe*Bytes` body they were intended for.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution using NSData

```
let data = NSData(bytes: arrayOfUInt8, length: arrayOfUInt8.count)
let pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> = data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
```