# Unable to understand how withUnsafeBytes method works

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I am trying to convert Data to UnsafePointer. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285026/swift-convert-data-to-unsafemutablepointerint8) where I can use withUnsafeBytes to get the bytes.

Then I did a small test my self to see I could just print out the bytes value of the string "abc"

```
let testData: Data = "abc".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

testData.withUnsafeBytes(
{(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in

    NSLog("\(bytes.pointee)")

})
```

But the output is just the value of one character, which is "a".

```
2018-07-11 14:40:32.910268+0800 SwiftTest[44249:651107] 97
```

How could I get the byte value of all three characters then?

Comment: Note that you can print all bytes without using `withUnsafeBytes:` Just `for byte in testData { print(byte) }`

Comment: @MartinR Didn't know this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "pointer" points to the address of the first byte in the sequence. If you want to want a pointer to the other bytes, you have to use *pointer arithmetic*, that is, move the pointer to the next address:

```
testData.withUnsafeBytes{ (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
    NSLog("\(bytes.pointee)")
    NSLog("\(bytes.successor().pointee)")
    NSLog("\(bytes.advanced(by: 2).pointee)")
}
```

or

```
testData.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
    NSLog("\(bytes[0])")
    NSLog("\(bytes[1])")
    NSLog("\(bytes[2])")
}
```

However, you must be aware of the byte size of `testData` and don't overflow it.

Comment: @MartinR Oh yes, forgotten the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting '97' because 'bytes' is pointing to the staring address of the 'testdata'.

you can get byte value of all three OR n number of characters like in the following code :

```
let testData: Data = "abc".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
print(testData.count)
testData.withUnsafeBytes(
    {(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
        for idx in 0..<testData.count {
            NSLog("\(bytes[idx])")
        }
})
```